# Cannot understand enums in java

Tags: java, enums

I was looking at an example code provided in my book

```
enum Coin
{
   PENNY(1),
   NICKEL(5),
   DIME(10),
   QUARTER(25);

   private final int denomValue;

   Coin(int denomValue)
   {
      this.denomValue = denomValue;
   }

   int denomValue()
   {
      return denomValue;
   }

   int toDenomination(int numPennies)
   {
      return numPennies / denomValue;
   }
}

public class Coins
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      if (args.length == 1)
      {
         int numPennies = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
         System.out.println(numPennies + " pennies is equivalent to:");
         int numQuarters = Coin.QUARTER.toDenomination(numPennies);
         System.out.println(numQuarters + " " + Coin.QUARTER.toString() +
                            (numQuarters != 1 ? "s," : ","));
         numPennies -= numQuarters * Coin.QUARTER.denomValue();
         int numDimes = Coin.DIME.toDenomination(numPennies);
         System.out.println(numDimes + " " + Coin.DIME.toString() +
                            (numDimes != 1 ? "s, " : ","));
         numPennies -= numDimes * Coin.DIME.denomValue();
         int numNickels = Coin.NICKEL.toDenomination(numPennies);
         System.out.println(numNickels + " " + Coin.NICKEL.toString() +
                            (numNickels != 1 ? "s, " : ", and"));
         numPennies -= numNickels*Coin.NICKEL.denomValue();
         System.out.println(numPennies + " " + Coin.PENNY.toString() +
                            (numPennies != 1 ? "s" : ""));
      }
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Denomination values:");
      for (int i = 0; i < Coin.values().length; i++)
         System.out.println(Coin.values()[i].denomValue());
   }
}
```

If enum is like a class, is it possible to have the same name for a method and field inside a class, as it has been done here with denomValue?

Why is it calling `int numQuarters = Coin.QUARTER.toDenomination(numPennies);` in this manner? Is `toDenomination()` static by default?

In the above case, what is the value of denomValue field? The output for this program hints that it should be equal to QUARTER. But how does that work? Is Coin.QUARTER equivalent to creating a coin object and passing QUARTER as it's constructor argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each of `PENNY`, `NICKEL` are instances of `Coin` class and are static, so they can be accessed as `Coin.PENNY`.

So when you do :

```
Coin.QUARTER.toDenomination(numPennies)
```

you are accessing the `QUARTER` instance of coin class and calling its `toDenomination()` method which is an instance method being called on `QUARTER` instance.

When you do:

```
PENNY(1) //this actually calls the constructor with one integer argument of Coin class
```

To check that PENNY is instance of `Coin` class:

```
System.out.println(Coin.PENNY.getClass());  //Will show you Coin
```

Comment: I have added the explanation for it too.

Comment: So QUARTER itself is an object of type Coin, and since it is a static member of Coin, it has to be accessed as Coin.QUARTER. Then we are calling the toDenomination() function of this QUARTER object. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes they are instances of Coin class.

Comment: ok thank you very much. What about `denomValue` being both a field and method? Is that allowed in any class in java? Or is it a special case for enums?

Comment: It is possible in java for a class to have a field and a method of same name. It is not special case with enum.

Answer (score 1):

`Enum`s are special classes as:

- They are constant classes.
- The enum values can only be accessed statically.

Hence why `Enum`s have a private constructor.

Once you have gotten the value, the declared methods and attributes can be accessed like an ordinary class.

the values of `denomValue` depends on the `Enum` value declared in `Coin` enum. For example: `PENNY` enum `denomValue` is `1` and will always be `1`.